# videoview failing to play rtmp and some other streams

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using a videoview with a mediacontroller to play rtmp, rtsp, m3u8 and http streams.
The problem is that they dont work on all my devices. Some devices play all streams, some cant play rtmp and some can only play some rtmp and some http streams, but not all of them.

I am thinking that it might be some kind of decoding/encoding issue? So i was hoping that someone out there can give me the answer.

I know that some apps uses the same streams and they work on all my devices, when i load their app for the first time, it says "Initializing Decoders", but i cant seem to find anything helpful about that, maybe you can point me at the right direction.

Here is the code that i am using to play the streams:

```
private void playVideo(string link) {
    videoView.setVisibility(VideoView.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    if (videoView.isPlaying()) { videoView.stopPlayback(); }
    MediaController media = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
    media.setAnchorView(videoView);
    media.setFocusable(false);
    media.setClickable(false);
    media.setLongClickable(false);
    videoView.setMediaController(media);
    videoView.setFocusable(false);
    videoView.setClickable(false);
    videoView.setLongClickable(false);
    videoView.setVideoPath(link);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(videoViewPreparedListener);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(videoViewCompletionListener);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(videoViewErrorListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vitamino library for your desired functionality.You have very few options for this and vitamino library is one of it.It will increase your apk size to 8 MB then your usual size if you want to compromise with it then it is good.Also it has limitations that in very rare case it does not support some cpu architecture.Overall it is good.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77008/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-shah-videoview-failing-to-play-rtmp-and-some-other-s).